# Selecting features for improving classification accuracy

Tags: machine-learning, classification, feature-selection

I have a dataset in which each sample has around 500 features. I know that in this feature set, some attributes are useful and may positively improve the classification accuracy. But some attributes are not useful and may even decrease classification accuracy. Problem is I don't know which of these attributes have positive effect. Can you please suggest some ways how I can find out those attributes which have positive effect and discard others which have negative effect?

Answer (score 1):

First, it is important to notice that finding the optimal subset of features is NP-hard (see [Wrappers for feature selection](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/0048/88621a4e4cee56b6633338a89aa036cf5ae5.pdf)). Hence, you look for computationally efficient, sub-optimal approaches.

There are many, many possibilities. The two most basic approaches are particular cases of greedy search: start with all (resp. none) of the features, and remove (add) the feature which leads to a least (biggest) decline (improvement) in the recognition rate (this so called wrapper methods are discussed in the first reference).

Correlation methods (for example, based on mutual information, see references on the corrensponding [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_selection) page).

More recently it random forest have proven to be efficient for this task (in addition to having a very good performance in many tasks). See [Variable selection using Random Forests](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00755489/file/PRLv4.pdf) for a description of a couple of basic heuristics based on the ranking of features provided by the random forest.

See this [blog](https://www.r-bloggers.com/random-forest-variable-importance/) entry for an intuitive explanation of the feature importance measure provided by the random forest algorithm.